# cron job script not executing terminus command

Tags: bash, scripts, kubuntu, cron, drupal

I'm new to cron jobs implementation. On my local, I have setup crontab on kubuntu system, but when the cronjob executed, it do not execute `terminus` commands inside it.
When I run terminus commands directly from terminal with sudo, it is getting executed successfully, but not from cronjob shell script.

```
$ whoami
$ aamir
$ which terminus
$ /usr/local/bin/terminus
```

test2.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo terminus auth:login --machine-token=xxxxxxx
sudo terminus command here
```

crontab entry As root user

```
$ sudo crontab -u root -e
07 15 24 * * /var/www/html/test2.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

In logs I can see this crontab entry is getting executed, but terminus command inside the script does not execute.
I guess it is not getting the correct path for terminus.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of redirecting output to /dev/null why don't you re-direct output to a log file so then you can see for yourself exactly what your script is doing and what errors you are getting. For example: `07 15 24 * * /var/www/html/test2.sh >> /path/to/my/logfile.log 2>&1`

Comment: @codlord I tried it. logfile is empty after executing cronjob.

Comment: I don't know anything about `terminus` but my suggestions would be you add some `echo` outputs to your script before each command so you can be sure what lines the script is getting to and also try specifying absolute path `/usr/local/bin/terminus` not just `terminus`.

Comment: Remove the two `sudo`s from your script.

Answer (score 0):

- **Never** run graphical applications, in this case terminal emulator `terminus` as root. Terminus is an end user application. Launch it only **as* a user **for** a user.
- **Never** use crontabs to launch a terminal emulator or any other graphical end user application, leave alone the crotab of root. If you want to auto launch a terminal emulator, in this case `terminus`, put it in the Startup Applications of each user that wished to have it loaded during startup.
- **Never** use `sudo` in a script. If needed for system administrative tasks, run the entire script with root privileges.